# Struggling with facet_grid including correct properties

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have a data set that has an uneven number of subcategories ('Thingies') per each main category ('Whereabouts'). I want to build a barplot that shows the subcategories on the x-axis, grouped by main category. However, I keep running into the issue where all of my subcategories are grouped into each category on the bar graph.

I can get the axis correct when I produce a box plot:

```
SpookyReport <- HalloweenData %>% mutate(Whereabouts = fct_relevel(Whereabouts, c("Dead", "Halfdead", "Alive"))) %>% 
  ggplot(HalloweenData, mapping = aes(y = Totalspook, x = Whereabouts, fill = Thingies)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=SpookyPalette) +
  labs(y="Total spook (spook-o-meters)", x=NULL) + ggtitle("Effect of losing my mind over this") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position="right") +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15)) 
SpookyReport
```

[Good box plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMDRX.png)

However, when I try to produce a bar plot with the following code:

```
SpookySumReport2<-ddply(HalloweenData, .(Thingies), summarise, .progress="text", mean.cm=mean(Totalspook),
                           SD.cm=sd(Totalspook),SE.cm=sd(Totalspook)/sqrt(length(Totalspook)))
SpookySumReport2


SpookyReport2 <-  HalloweenData %>% mutate(Whereabouts = fct_relevel(Whereabouts, c("Dead", "Halfdead", "Alive"))) %>% 
  ggplot(LiveInocsContrasts, mapping = aes(x=Thingies, y=Totalspook, fill= Thingies)) +
  geom_bar(stat='summary') +
  geom_beeswarm(aes(x = Thingies, y = Totalspook), dodge.width = 0.9, alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_errorbar(data = SpookySumReport2, aes(x = Thingies, y = mean.cm, ymin=mean.cm-SE.cm,ymax=mean.cm+SE.cm, colour=Thingies),
                color = 'black', width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=SpookyPalette) +
  facet_grid(~ Whereabouts, 
             scales = "free_x",
             space = "free_x",
             switch = "x") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, units = "cm"), 
        strip.placement = "outside", 
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs(y="Total spook (spook-o-meters)", x=NULL) + ggtitle("Effect of losing my mind over this") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15)) 
SpookyReport2
```

I get something like this:
[Bad bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89VPR.png)

As you can see, all of the subcategories are present in the main categories, but that's not how my data is grouped in my dataset. This is my first time working with facet_grid, so perhaps I am doing something wrong? Can anyone identify the problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: SpookySumReport2 has Thingies for every Whereabouts, but HalloweenData does not. All the data that exists is plotted. You presumably don't want all the Thingies in SpookySumReport2 that don't correspond to what's in HalloweenData.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @ Jon Spring. Thank you for your comment! I solved the issue by changing SpookySumReport2: SpookySumReport2<-ddply(HalloweenData, .(Thingies, Whereabouts), summarise, .progress="text", mean.cm=mean(TotalSpook),
                        SD.cm=sd(TotalSpook),SE.cm=sd(TotalSpook)/sqrt(length(TotalSpook)))
SpookySumReport2